# SpringApplicationBuilder error while starting SpringBoot Application using 2.4.0

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate from SpringBoot 1.5 to 2.4.0 . While doing so Im getting an error related to SpringApplicationBuilder.

The pom.xml looks like below:

...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
  
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

....other dependencies follows

Error I have attached in the pic :
[image]

I tried adding below but it doesnot work:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
         </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: you can refer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: All my findings in one place: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/0aa4ee8453e897b33e2da9319ebbc717

Comment: Did you solve this issue?